# Deleting user affects incremental unique reference which uses count of matching results. How to keep increment?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-users

For a variety of reasons I might need to delete a user. A soft delete in which I simply delete all identifiable info and leaving some anonymised might not be an option. Additionally, if I delete the user inside the django admin site then it would be a hard delete.

The issue is that I have a model for the user which includes first_name, last_name, company_name, reference_id etc. The reference_id is created by using first 3 consonants of the last name, first 3 letters of the first name and then an incremental 3 digit number starting with 001. If any of the names have less than 3 letters the missing letters are replaced with an 'X'. The numeric part uses a model lookup with first 6 letters, counting the number of results. incrementing by 1 and using zfill to fill the missing number of digits. A full reference_id is like this: MDVTAS001 for example:

```
first_name_tres = first_name.lower()[0:3].ljust(3,'x')
print("first name 3: " + first_name_tres)
last_name_tres = last_name.lower().translate({ord(i): None for i in 'aeiou'})[0:3].ljust(3,'x')
print("last name 3: " + last_name_tres)
user_ref_count =  str(ProfileMember.objects.filter(reference_id__contains=(last_name_tres + first_name_tres)).count()+1).zfill(3)
print("user ref count: " + user_ref_count)
reference_id = last_name_tres + first_name_tres + user_ref_co
```

The issue with this method is that if for example is 2 users ie. MDVTAS001 and MDVTAS002 and I delete MDVTAS001 then the count is 1 and the next matching user will get MDVTAS002 but that already exists and since I am setting this value to be unique it will fail. Now if have 5 users and 2 are deleted the issue is compounded further.

How can I ensure that all the value is always incrementing higher even if users have been deleted?

Comment: Any chance you could inactivate rather than delete?

Comment: No. because for example GDPR we need to delete data after x amount of time if requested or if people remove their accounts. Anonymising might have worked if we weren't considering the fact that records could be perma deleted from the admin interface

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49461740/5320906) help?

Comment: @snakecharmerb not quite since the serial is dependent on those first 6 letters (UUID i suppose) and its not clear to me how that would work here

Answer (score 1):

```
last_record = ProfileMember.objects.filter(reference_id__startswith=(last_name_tres + first_name_tres)).order_by('reference_id').last()
if last_record:
    reference_id = last_name_tres + first_name_tres + str(int(last_record.reference_id[-3:]) + 1).zfill(3)
else:
    reference_id = last_name_tres + first_name_tres + '001'
```

Comment: This largely solves the problem but means if the last record was the one deleted it could be reused. I suppose i should be satisfied with that.